# Print a list of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, methods, console-application

I want to know how to return list and how to display it on console window.

Thus one goes on main program.

```
ICompany e4 = new Company();
e4.ViewEmployee();
Console.WriteLine("The details are", e4);
break;
```

This is the method which is used to print the employee list

```
public List<IEmployee> ViewEmployee() {

    IEmployee e7=new Employee();
    foreach (IEmployee e in emplist) {
        return emplist;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's really unclear what you want to do. Obviously you're very new to programming and should have begun proper learning using a standard book or tutorial. That's one of the reasons your questions got down-voted.

Anyway,

1. To return a list of type `T` (in your case, `T` is `Employee` class), simply have a method (within your class but outside `main` method) that returns a `List<T>`.
2. To print the list out, you will need to iterate through the list inside the `main(String[] args)` method in your `Program` class.

   ```
   var yourList = YourMethodThatReturnsList();
   foreach (Employee item in yourList)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
   ```

NB: if you do not like what is being printed out, you can simply override `ToString()` method in your `Employee` class.